# AWS EC2 Windows CloudWatch Agent to push memory and disk space metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-systems-manager

I am trying to configure custom metrics for windows server in EC2. I need memory utilization and free disk space metrics from perfmon. So, the document says we can use AWS SSM and cloudwatch agent to push these metrics. Have enabled SSM and attached role and everything on EC2. The config file I created in the path "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AmazonCloudWatchAgent\" is amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json. The contents of this file are:

```
{
"agent": {
    "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
    "logfile": "c:\\Program Files\\Amazon\\CloudWatchAgent\\Logs\\amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log"
  },
"metrics": {
"metrics_collected": {
  "statsd": {},
  "LogicalDisk": {
    "measurement": [
      {"name": "Free Megabytes", "unit": "String"},
      {"name": "LogicalDisk % Disk Read Time", "rename": "DISK_READ"},
      "% Disk Write Time"
    ],
    "resources": [
      "*"
    ]
  },
  "Memory": {
    "metrics_collection_interval": 5,
    "measurement": [
      "Available MBytes"
    ],
    "append_dimensions": {
      "d3": "win_bo"
    }
  },
"append_dimensions": {
  "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}"
},
"aggregation_dimensions" : [["InstanceId"], ["d1"],[]]
}
}
}
```

Now, when I try to push this config file to cloudwatch agent using command line ".\amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl.ps1 -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c file:.\amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json", I get an error as attached here:

[image]

Can someone please guide me to achieve what I am looking for. I am not sure about this error, and stuck here. Any support would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd take metrics out of the file until it works, then you can diagnose the one that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Cloudwatch Agent error messages are quite misleading.

I think the problem is with your "Free Megabytes" measurement - try "% Free Space" instead. The name should match the name of the metric in Performance Monitor. Possibly some of your other measurements are also incorrect.